# not getting SELECT COUNT to work in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, count, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am new to phpmyadmin. I am not getting simple COUNT function to work.

I created a database with 8 tables to handle all kinds of contacts, personal and business.
I have been practicing queries and joins (by copying from tutorials) and so far all have worked.
I have been trying to do a COUNT but I am getting an error.
"#1060 - you have an error in your SQL syntax; ......"

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM tblcontacts
```

if I erase the word count it will give all the rows of tblcontacts
I have tried rewriting and changing puntuation , ; '' "" () capitals, but no result.

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: no need of space between count and brackets, it should be select count(*) from tblcontacts;

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow the space after `COUNT`.

Comment: that solves it. thank you very much. I tried changing so many things, but didnt think about the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be

```sql
select COUNT(*) from tblcontacts;
```